# Laravel - Failing to get results of collection with 'when'

Tags: laravel

Trying to optimise my code and not have a bunch of if statements and converting to using 'when'.

Old code was as follows (worked fine):

```
    $bursary_administrator = BursaryAdministrator::findOrFail(\Auth::user()->userable_id);

    $search = $request->search;
    if($search == ''){
        $students = $bursary_administrator->students()
            ->select('students.id',DB::raw("CONCAT(student_name,' ',student_middle_names,' ',student_surname) AS `student_complete_name`"))
            ->orderby('student_complete_name','asc')->get();
    }else{
        $students = $bursary_administrator->students()
            ->select('students.id',DB::raw("CONCAT(student_name,' ',student_middle_names,' ',student_surname) AS `student_complete_name`"))
            ->whereraw("CONCAT(student_name,' ',student_middle_names,' ',student_surname) like ?",['%'.$search.'%'])
            ->orderby('student_complete_name','asc')->get();
    }
```

Then I converted to using 'when' and also added an extra condition (active):

```
    $bursary_administrator = BursaryAdministrator::findOrFail(\Auth::user()->userable_id);

    $students = $bursary_administrator->students()->select('students.id',DB::raw("CONCAT(student_name,' ',student_middle_names,' ',student_surname) AS `student_complete_name`"));
    $students->when(request('search') != '', function ($q) {
        return $q->whereraw("CONCAT(student_name,' ',student_middle_names,' ',student_surname) like ?",['%'.request('search').'%']);
    })->when(request('active') == true, function ($q) {
        return $q->whereIn('status',[1,4,6,7]);
    });
    $students->orderby('student_complete_name','asc')->get();

    $response = array();
    foreach($students as $student){
        $response[] = array(
            "id"=>$student->id,
            "text"=>$student->student_complete_name
        );
    }
```

However, getting errors (the below is from tinker testing):
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in Psy Shell code on line 2
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'student_complete_name' of non-object in Psy Shell code on line 2

What have I done wrong? I was folowing https://laraveldaily.com/less-know-way-conditional-queries/ and the difference is that there they were using a query, and I used it 'directly' on the model?

Comment: Assuming you're returning `$response`? this is an array, not an object - can you clarify which var you are returning?

Comment: Also, could you drop a print_r() or dd() of your `$student` in the first iteration of your foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your problem is you are trying to loop an QueryBuilder and not the results of it. Which you do not assign to anything.

```
$students->orderby('student_complete_name','asc')->get();
```

To fix it.

```
$students = $students->orderby('student_complete_name','asc')->get();
```

But wait, there is more. I think you can make this a little more clear.

In your when boolean statements, not equal empty string, is equivalent to just checking the string as `(bool) $string`. Way more readable secondly, PHP's type juggling will convert a lot of cases to true. So if active is any string unless 0, it will return true.

Instead of making a transformation array, let `Laravel` handle the transformation. Make your calculated name, as an accessor and add it to the response with appends. Therefor in your `Student.php` model. Add the following.

```
class Student {
    protected $appends = ['name'];

    public function getNameAttribute(): string
    {
        return $this->attributes['student_complete_name'] ?? '';
    }
}
```

Now you whole code can be as simple as.

```
$bursary_administrator = BursaryAdministrator::findOrFail(\Auth::user()->userable_id);

$students = $bursary_administrator->students()->select('students.id',DB::raw("CONCAT(student_name,' ',student_middle_names,' ',student_surname) AS `student_complete_name`"));

$students->when(request('search'), function ($q) {
    return $q->whereraw("CONCAT(student_name,' ',student_middle_names,' ',student_surname) like ?",['%'.request('search').'%']);
})->when(request('active') === '1', function ($q) {
    return $q->whereIn('status',[1,4,6,7]);
});

return $students->orderby('student_complete_name','asc')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the extra tips :) The reason I cant return the "get()" straight away is because the handler is expecting "id" and "text". Unless I've missed something and you can specify "mutators" for get? ie, something like ```return $students->orderby('student_complete_name','asc')->get(['id','student_complete_name' AS 'text']);```

Comment: Oh, never mind, seems like I can do exactly that! Not sure if it will work on an already aliased name, but will work around it, proper syntax (for future visitors) would be: ```return $students->orderby('student_complete_name','asc')->get(['id','student_complete_name AS text']);```

Comment: If expect text, change the appends method instead. getTextAttribute() and protected $appends = ['text']; It is waste of time to handle transformation manually.